# lftp to read from list of sites and then execute multiple commands

Tags: bash, loops, ftp, command-line-interface, lftp

I need lftp to connect to a list of hosts from a list file which are in ip address format.  Then, if a ftp server is up, log that address (and if possible, device type, in this case routers) to a text file. For the servers that are up, I need it to connect without any credentials given and then use find to map the directories and files, then output that data to a file named after the server address. I tried to write a for loop with ftp but it was unsuccessful.  I think lftp going to be the best option for what I need to do.

cat list6.txt | lftp | grep connected > livehosts.txt

also:

for i [in LIST ]; do ftp; "echo welcome> *"; done > [IP Address].txt

Comment: Hi! Please follow SO [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Give some *real* issues you're facing.

Comment: I need to know what servers from my list are up and grep the output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know what servers from my list are up and grep the output to
>   a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in $(<list6.txt)
do  # ftp may say "Connection timed out" or "Connection refused"
    ftp $server <<<'' |& grep -q Connection || echo $server
done >livehosts.txt
```